# Hacer backup en oracle db usando triggers

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, trigger

tengo 2 tablas identicas,solo cambia el nombre **tabla1** y **tabla2**, cuando se ingresen 3 registros en la **tabla1** la informacion de esta tabla se debe copiar a la **tabla 2** y la **tabla 1** debe volver a quedar vacia.

> Se debe llegar a la solucion usando triggers (disparadores).

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA1(
ID_1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40));

CREATE TABLE TABLA2(
ID_1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40));

SELECT * FROM TABLA1;
SELECT * FROM TABLA2;


SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DISP_BACKUP
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLA1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
CURSOR CUR_CUENTA IS SELECT * FROM TABLA1;
--CURSOR CUR_CUENTA IS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1;
var_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
--CURCHOISE SQL%ROWCOUNT;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('NUMERO DE REGISTROS EN TABLA 1' || CUR_CUENTA%ROWCOUNT 
);
--OPEN CUR_CUENTA;
IF CUR_CUENTA%ROWCOUNT > 3 THEN
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (ID_1,NOMBRE) VALUES (:NEW.ID_1,:NEW.NOMBRE);
END IF;
DELETE FROM TABLA1;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Lo podrias hacer creando un trigger before insert en la tabla1. En el codigo del trigger cuentas los registros de la tabla y le sumas 1 (este 1 es por el registros que estas a punto de insertar), si al contarlo da 3 lo que haces es un insert into tabla2 select * from tabla1, seguido de un insert del registro actual a la tabla2 y por ultimo un truncate algo asi: execute immediate 'truncate table  table1' para asi dejar la tabla1 en blanco